# CSS menu icon not visible on ipad?

Tags: html, css, ipad, ios7, mobile-safari

I have an off-canvas navigation menu for a responsive website, and for the most part it's working fine (the icon doesn't match my site, but that can wait).

The problem I have is that the hamburger menu icon in the top left displays when I shrink my browser window (Chrome), on my android phone (Samsung S5) and on a viewport tester (Brad Frost's [ISH](http://bradfrost.com/demo/ish/)) but on my boss's iPad (4th Gen - Model A1458 - iOS 7)? Nothing.

Is there a reason that a div would be visible in chrome and not in safari? Code below.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Lable for #showmenu to hide the menu/uncheck the checkbox -->
<label class="toggle" for="toggle"><div class="fa fa-2x fa-bars"></div></label>

<!-- Menu content -->
<div class="menuContent">
    <div id="smallMenu" class="<%= Request("MainID") %>">
    <div id="Div1">
        <div class="smallMenu-main-categories-holder">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptSmall" runat="server">
                <headerTemplate>
                    <div class="smallMenu-main-categories">
                        <ul>
                </headerTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hlCategory" runat="server" CssClass="white"></asp:HyperLink></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <footerTemplate>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </footerTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu                               { display: block; width: 180px; height: 100%; top: 0px; z-index: 9999; position:absolute;}
#menu  .toggle                      {top: 5px; left: 180px; padding:10px; position: absolute;}
#toggle                             {display: none;}
/* Pushing the Menu off the canvas */
#menu                               {left: -180px; -webkit-transition: left 1s;transition: left 1s;}
/* Showing the menu then the Checkbox is checked */
#toggle:checked + #menu             {left: 0; -webkit-transition: left 1s; transition: left 1s;}
```

The Div in question is this one: `<label class="toggle" for="toggle"><div class="fa fa-2x fa-bars"></div></label>` which is part of FontAwesome's icon pack and I'm using the follow CSS to get the style.

**FontAwesome**

```
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.fa-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.fa-bars:before {
  content: "\f0c9";
}
```

I'm assuming that if it's not going to display on ipads, I will also have problems with iphones and other devices too.

Comment: your not the only one, i tested one my web's on an ipad recently and half the things were screwed. Now im not sure why you are getting this problem, but i suggest to target ipads with custom CSS. so for instance if you can borrow an ipad for testing use javascript or jquery to detect when your web is running on an ipad and load in a custom CSS file. That way you dont adjust the main css file that works on  pretty much everywhere else and just concentrate on the ipad. with a custom css file at least you wont get other issues down the line because your CSS  is concentrated  on the ipad's.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was hoping to avoid adding another CSS file to the mix though... there are so many on this site already...